# Flex column text is not proper on the right side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have made a flex column but the arrow on the right side is not proper, and it's hidden. It should be like the left arrow and should point to the left.

Left side i use `left: 0;`
Right side i use `right: 0;`
I can't figure out why the right side is wrong

https://jsfiddle.net/wa04ytLn/2/

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

#arleft {
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

#arright {
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">

  <div id="cleft" class="col-3 col-xs-12 bg-info">
    collapse left
  </div>
  <div id="cmid" class="col col-xs-12">
    <div class="d-none d-md-flex" id="arleft">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-md-flex" id="arright">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="cright" class="col-3 col-xs-12 bg-info">
    collapse right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You JSfiddle doesn't show any arrow including the left one as you have described. I tried to run t in my browser to see the same. Please post a screenshot that describes your question.

Comment: try to use z-index:2 on #arright

Comment: @JSDEV have you run it on Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Adding "right:0" only positions the red line to the right side of the div. If we take that code out we can see what is happening.

[image]

As you can see the arrow is positioned similar to the left red line. 
If you want the column to begin from the right. you can use "flex-direction: row-reverse;"

And this will yield you your desired output.

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="cleft" class="col-3 col-xs-12 bg-info">
    collapse left
  </div>
  <div id="cmid" class="col col-xs-12">
    <div class="d-none d-md-flex" id="arleft">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-md-flex" id="arright">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="cright" class="col-3 col-xs-12 bg-info">
    collapse right
  </div>
</div>
```

__

```
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

#arleft {
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

#arright {
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Here is the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bzry4Ltg/

Answer (score 1):

try row-reverse

Add this code in css code, it will be as you want.

```
#arright {
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: flex-end;

  /* add row-reverse */
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding following css to the arrow to the right?

```
.fa-arrow-left {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Ref - https://jsfiddle.net/3trmdkfg/